# NameError: name 'altitude' is not defined

Tags: python

I have this gps code which gets gps data and writes to the journal:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

from systemd import journal
import gps
import time
import threading
import datetime

# Listen on port 2947 (gpsd) of localhost
session = gps.gps("localhost", "2947")
session.stream(gps.WATCH_ENABLE | gps.WATCH_NEWSTYLE)

while True:
    try:
        report = session.next() # Wait for a 'TPV' report and display 
the current time

        # To see all report data, uncomment the line below
        #print report

        if report['class'] == 'TPV':
            if hasattr(report, 'time'):
                timestamp = (time.time()*1000)
                #print timestamp

            if hasattr(report, 'lat'):
                latitude = report.lat
                #print latitude

            if hasattr(report, 'lon'):
                longitude = report.lon
                #print longitude    

            if hasattr(report, 'alt'):
                altitude = report.alt
                #print altitude

        else:
            timestamp = (time.time()*1000)
            latitude = 0
            longitude = 0 
            altitude = 0

        journal.send(
        channel = 'gps',
        priority = journal.Priority.INFO,
        timestamp = "%f" % (timestamp),
        latitude = "%f" % (latitude),
        longitude = "%f" % (longitude), 
        altitude = "%f" % (altitude), 
        )

except KeyError:
    pass
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    quit()
except StopIteration:
    session = None
    print "GPSD has terminated"
```

And I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "gps-messi.py", line 57, in <module>
    altitude = "%f" % (altitude),
NameError: name 'altitude' is not defined
```

The funny part is the code works perfectly fine sometimes and sometimes it gives me this error. I can't understand what I should so to make it work correctly all the time. Does it have something to do with the she bang?

Comment: You should always check to see if a variable is defined before attempting to format the string. You have no guarentee that the variable will be defined when you attempt to get it from the lib.

Comment: Perhaps it's a typo? `if hasatr(report, 'alt'):` should be `hasattr`?

Comment: BTW your ``else`` belongs only to the last ``if``.

Comment: Why are you overwriting previously specified timestamps, latitudes, longitudes, and altitudes if there is no `speed` attribute? There appear to be *lots* of indentations problems with this code.

Comment: And why are you ignoring `report.time` if it *is* present?

Comment: `hasattr` is just a wrapper around `getattr` that catches an exception. Just use `getattr(report, 'time', time.time()*1000)`, etc. instead.

Comment: @MattCremeens Sorry that was a typo here. But the code is fine. In the code, it is 'hasattr' only.

Comment: @Psytho That was a mistake. I have made the edit. Take a look at the code again.

Comment: @chepner Yeah I am sorry about that. That's a mistake here on the forum. But it is all fine on my Pi. I am not using gps time because, I need to log system time only. Hence, time.time

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My guess is that `if hasattr(report, 'alt'):` does not resolve to `True`, then

```
if hasattr(report, 'alt'):
    altitude = report.alt
```

will not assign anything to `altitude` and there for when you get to here

```
journal.send(
    channel = 'gps',
    priority = journal.Priority.INFO,
    timestamp = "%f" % (timestamp),
    latitude = "%f" % (latitude),
    longitude = "%f" % (longitude), 
    altitude = "%f" % (altitude), 
    )
```

you are essentially using `altitude` before it gets assigned. To avoid this, you could initialize `altitude` to some value before you get to this point with

```
altitude=0
```

Doing so will ensure that it is assigned before it is used and you shouldn't get that error.

Comment: Thanks a lot Matt. So which is better? Initialising the variables before the if statement or initialising the variables globally?

Comment: I think it's enough to initialize before the if statement. Maybe right after `report` is assigned.

Comment: In fact, you probably should do that for all of the variables used in `journal.send`.

Comment: Done. Thanks Matt.

Comment: Glad to help. I've certainly received plenty of help here. All the best.

Answer (score 3):

It seems the report from session has no attribute named 'altitude' depending on the cases. If the attribute 'alt' exists it creates a variable altitude allowing the code to work. If the attribute 'alt' does not exist the code will fail. Initiate the variables before the if statements and it will work fine.

Answer (score 2):

I agree with @wesgur you are initiating the `alititude` in a n `if` statemtent but there are situations where that `if` statement's conditions are not met and the program has no definition for `altitude`

Answer (score 1):

Move the block

```
    timestamp = (time.time()*1000)
    latitude = 0
    longitude = 0 
    altitude = 0
```

before `if report['class'] == 'TPV':` branch.
So you will always have your four variables initialized.

Comment: So which is better? Initialising the variables before the if statement or initialising the variables globally?

Comment: What if ``if report['class'] == 'TPV'`` is true but there is no attribute ``"alt"``? ``altitude`` remains uninitialized in your current code  as you have already seen.

Comment: Yeah I got that. But where should I initialize? before the if or gloabally is better?

Comment: I don't think there would be any difference in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot everyone. This is what my code looks like now. I tested it and it seems fine. But in case if I am still slipping somewhere, can someone just check for the indentation of the line journal.send? If what I have done is right (I have modified names of some of the variables and added speed):

```
#!/usr/bin/python

from systemd import journal
import gps
import time
import threading
import datetime

# Listen on port 2947 (gpsd) of localhost
session = gps.gps("localhost", "2947")
session.stream(gps.WATCH_ENABLE | gps.WATCH_NEWSTYLE)

while True:
    try:
        report = session.next() # Wait for a 'TPV' report and display the current time  
        # To see all report data, uncomment the line below
        #print report

        timestamp = 0        
        latitude = 0
        longitude = 0 
        altitude = 0
        speed = 0

        if report['class'] == 'TPV':

            if hasattr(report, 'time'):
                timestamp = (time.time()*1000)
                #print timestamp

            if hasattr(report, 'lat'):
                latitude = report.lat
                #print latitude

            if hasattr(report, 'lon'):
                longitude = report.lon
                #print longitude  

            if hasattr(report, 'alt'):
                altitude = report.alt
                #print altitude

            if hasattr(report, 'speed'):
                speed = report.speed
                #print speed

        journal.send(
        channel = 'gps',
        priority = journal.Priority.INFO,
        timestamp = "%f" % (timestamp),
        lat_deg = "%f" % (latitude),
        lon_deg = "%f" % (longitude), 
        alt_m = "%f" % (altitude), 
        speed_mps = "%f" % (speed),
        )


    except KeyError:
        pass
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        quit()
    except StopIteration:
        session = None
        print "GPSD has terminated"
```